# Add specific words to WordPress custom type slug

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, slug

I have a WordPress installation with a custom type (places) wich produces this permalink structure:

http://example.com/places/the-first-site/

And I would like to show all my sites like this:

http://example.com/places/visit-the-first-site-and-enjoy/

where 'visit' and 'and-enjoy' would be always those specific words (constants).

Even better I would like to put a custom taxonomy I have (year) as a metadata

places/visit-the-first-site-and-enjoy-1985/

I can access the DB and modify the post name of all post, but I would have to do for the new post also, and I'm looking for some automated rule, but can't find how to do.

Maybe some rewrite rule, but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas??

Comment: Change permalink of each post to what you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **do not** have to **edit** anything in your **database** *nor* any **codes** in your WordPress installation; you **can achieve** that directly from your **WordPress administration panel**.

From your *Dashboard*, click on the *Permalink* sub-menu under *Settings*; [there](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen), you will have to select the *Custom Structure* option and set it as follow in order to achieve your desired effect:

> **`/places/visit-%postname%-and-enjoy-%year%/`**

*Please note: here, we made use of both **`%postname%`** and **`%year%`** [Structure Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags) so as to get names of posts with their corresponding year of publication respectively.*

Don't forget to click on the *Save Changes* button on the page in order to effect your changes.

*... Read more on [Permaklinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) (for general knowledge).*

*For a **custom post type and taxonomies** as expressed further in comments, you will need a custom solution which will require a little bit of coding and or tweaking, depending on your abilities; you may use this handy plugin ([Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)) from the [WordPress.org Plugins repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).*

*This [**posts**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39862/105480) should equally be of great help to you, to getting started and understanding further, should you chose to code.*

Comment: I know that, but if I do so, it Will change the slug for all the site, I only want to do it for a custom type of post.

Answer (score 0):

You have différent hook like save_post or pending_to_publish, where you can set or change the "post_name" (that's corresponds to the permalink slug).

Answer (score 0):

To Add specific words to WordPress custom type slug You have to Register custom rewrite rules.
suppose this is Your URL http://example.com/places/the-first-site !
 and you have a post type places.

```
  function add_rewrite_rules()
 {
 $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%places%', '([^/]+)', 'places=');
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%state%', '([^/]+)', 'state=');

$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('places', 'places/visit-%state%-and-enjoy/', false);
 }
  function permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename)
  {
   $no_data = 'no-data';
   $post_id = $post->ID;
 if($post->post_type != 'story' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
  return $permalink;
   $state = get_post_meta($post_id, 'location', true);
 if(!$state)

    $state = $no_data;

      $permalink = str_replace('%state%', $state, $permalink);
     return $permalink;
   } 
   add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
   add_filter('post_type_link', 'permalinks', 10, 3);
```

put this code in your custom post type plugin. and if get page not found error please change your permalink setting. or make a custom template file to show this post.